# Looping through id and fire function

Tags: javascript

im trying to loop through an id i specified inside html  `<div class="like-btn" id="clickme"></div>`

```
var button = document.getElementById("clickme")
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    var like_button = button[i]
    count = 0;
    like_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        count += 1;
        button[0].innerHTML = "" + count;
    });
}
```

im not getting any errors but the counter is not working either.

Comment: It's id selector so you won't get an array of DOM nodes in return, it is going to be a specific element. So you won't be able to. iterate over it

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, as its name implies.  How are you expecting to "loop through" a single element?  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Document#getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) does not give you an array. For that reason `length` is `undefined` and your code does simply nothing because `0 < undefined === false`.

You can replace `document.getElementById("clickme")` with `document.querySelectorAll("#clickme")` and it should work. But you should instead choose to use a `class` instead of an `id` as your selector, since `id`'s should be unique.